# Image rendering differently in emulator vs. browser with IONIC css

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am building an app using IONIC 2. In an IONIC button, I am adding a custom image. I need to scale the image to be the same (/similar) size to the other icons, so I have the following css:

```
  .buttons .key img {
     max-width: 34px;
     max-height: 34px;
     height: auto;
     width: auto;
     vertical-align: center;
     transform:rotate(45deg);
      -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
      -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
      -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
   }
```

in browser:

[image]

on emulator:
[image]

Why is the key image stretching and how can I work around this? Any ideas would be much appreciated, as this is really got me.

NB: I have a shadow of this on the IONIC Forum, [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/images-rendering-differently-between-browser-and-emulator/47366)

Comment: I think all the images are stretching, its just the key is the most noticeable.

Comment: @Guy I have updated the picture, I don't think they are, it was just the screen shot